# Override wagtail BaseSiteSetting template

Tags: python, django-templates, wagtail

I've been trying for some time to override the edit.html template for a single BaseSiteSetting in wagtail.
I'm not sure if this is even possible. My overrides for ModelAdmin templates are working just fine by using the following directory structure:
[ModelAdmin index.html override](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMTIs.png)

Is the same possible for my setting? Which is located in my success_stories app models.

I've looked through the `wagtail/contrib/settings/templates/wagtailsettings/edit.html` file but it's unclear to me how to do this. I've always worked with headless wagtail and don't have a lot of experience with templates.

The wagtail docs only seem to mention ModelAdmin overrides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be done via standard Django template overrides: The first template that matches wins the cake.

In your case the template for the Wagtail Settings contrib module is located under `templates/wagtailsettings/edit.html` which means that in your app's `template` directory you have to make the exact same setup:

`<you_app_directory>/templates/wagtailsettings/edit.html`

Then depending on how you have setup your template discovery and/or have setup your app loading order one of the above templates will match first. So in order for your template to be the first one to match you can do two things:

Alter the loading order of your apps and make sure that your app comes **before** the `wagtail.contrib.settings` in your `INSTALLED_APPS` Django settings listing:

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
   ...
   <your_app>,
   wagtail.contrib.settings
   ...
]
```

Or you can alter how templates are discovered by Django by changing the `TEMPLATES` setting:

```py
TEMPLATES = [
    {
       ...
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates'],
        "APP_DIRS": True,
       ...
    },
]
```

Notice that `DIRS` comes before `APP_DIRS`, the order here matters as well. First Django will look in the directories you specify in `DIRS`, if nothing matched it will continue to look in the installed application directories.

Note that with the latter method `BASE_DIR / 'templates'` is a single templates directory at the root of your project.

Usually, if overriding third-party templates, the first method is used.

Comment: Thank you, this clears things up.
At some point I had the correct directory structure but I didn't think of changing the order of the INSTALLED_APPS.