# Wagtail: Redirect after saving Django model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, wagtail

I'm trying to redirect the user to a custom HTML page after saving a `BaseSiteSetting` model in Wagtail 4.1.1

I'm not sure how to accomplish this, the `BaseSiteSetting` inherits from Django `models.Model` which means it's possible to override the `save()` function but how would I do the actual redirect without having access to the request?

Another acceptable solution would be to add an extra button in the CMS by overriding the default `BaseSiteSetting HTML template` but I can't seem to get that working either, except for ModelAdmin templates. [I've opened a StackOverflow question about that here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74811215/override-wagtail-basesitesetting-template)

My view of the custom HTML page:

```
def sync(request):
    return render(request, "import.html", {"WS_PROTOCOL": settings.WS_PROTOCOL})
```

My BaseSiteSetting model:

```
@register_setting
class AnonymousSuccessStoryImportSetting(BaseSiteSetting):
    """
    Setting for importing anonymous success stories.
    """

    file = models.FileField(
       upload_to="success_story_imports/%Y/%m/%d/",
        validators=[validate_file_extension],
        help_text="Upload a CSV file, then click 'Save' afterwards",
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Importer"
```

I've looked around for possible solutions and found some wagtail hooks but these only apply to the Wagtail Page model, for example, `after_publish_page`.

It's unfortunate that there's no hook for standard Django models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like BaseSiteSettings is one of the models that has not been converted to use class-based views. So I think you need to monkey patch this edit method to change the 'after save' redirect here: https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/main/wagtail/contrib/settings/views.py#L121

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for your reply, I was hoping it would be possible to do this using a view but your solution works for now.